# Created Input from javascript not delivering its value

Tags: javascript, php, html

i created an input from javascript like this:

```
<form action='' method='post' name='create'>
    <span id="duration"></span>
</form>


function duration(){
        document.getElementById('duration').innerHTML += "<label>Deadline  :</label><input type='date' name='deadline' id='deadline' onchange='pengumuman(this.value)' class='form-control' min=" + date('now', 0, 'ymd') + " max=" + date('now', 7, 'ymd') + ">";
        }
```

And i created a span inside a form, but whenever I tried to submit this form and print I got no value `(string(0) = "") or $_GET['deadline']; (and i just tried $_POST['deadline'] also but still the same. not found Undefined index: deadline`  from this input. How to fix this? Do created input from javascript can't be inputted in form?

Comment: I'm not a PHP dev, however, I think you need to use: `$_POST['deadline'];`

Comment: Can you share your php code? Also, there is no submit button in your form so how you are posting the form?

Answer (score 1):

POST parameters come in on [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php), not [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php). `$_GET` is for GET parameters. Since your form has `method='post'`, it will send its data via POST.

---

The `min=" + date('now', 0, 'ymd') + " max=" + date('now', 7, 'ymd') +` part of your code also looks suspect, unless you've defined a JavaScript function alled `date`.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and it still the same, i got Undefined index: deadline.
And function on min and max attribute are nothing to do with it cause it works like a charm.

Comment: @AdiHanifSedar: Show the code you're getting that error from. We can't help you with code we can't see.